# Validate custom mail id using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Validate email address

Valid address are:

```
custom@domain.kld #(kld can be any length string)
custom1.custom2@domain.kld
custom1_custom2@domain.kld
custom1+custom2@domain.kld
```

If email id is custom@sub.domain.kld then ignore all that is sub.domain

I tried below script;

```
import re
bool(re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', addressToVerify))
```

It is not working for inputs:

```
input mail id: my+email@gmail.com 

Expected output :

   True

Actual output: 

   False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
bool(re.match('^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', addressToVerify))
```